# Count number of times a row repeats in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, count, row, unique

I have a table (Table 1) which lists several sports venues by type in several countries and cities in each country. I have an individual entry for each venue in one row of the table.

Table 1 has 5 columns, starting in column A: (A) Country; (B) City; (C) Type of Sport; (D) Address; (E) Capacity of Venue.

In a different sheet I would like to build another table (Table 2) where a formula would count the number of rows where information in columns A, B and C of Table 1 repeats. In other words, Table 2 will have only one entry per country, city and type of sport.
In Table 2, there will only be another entry for the same country and city in case the type of sport is different; there will only be another entry for the same country and type of sport if the city is different, etc.

If Table 1 were this:

[image]

Table 2 would have to be like this:

[image]

I have tried to do this with a `COUNTIF` formula but did not succeed. From what I have researched, I might need a script to do it but I cannot seem to be able to.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could also be done with Query:

```
=QUERY(A1:C7,"Select A,B,C,count(A) group by A,B,C",1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF( 'Sheet1'!A:A & 'Sheet1'!B:B & 'Sheet1!C:C', A2:A6 & B2:B6 & C2:C6))`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Add a column F labeled 'No.of venues' and in F2 enter:

```
=countifs($A$2:$A$7,A2,$B$2:$B$7,B2,$C$2:$C$7,C2)
```

Copy the formula down.

Then query the above with this:

```
=UNIQUE(query(Sheet1!A1:F7,"select A,B,C,F"))
```

Put the above formula in A1 of a different sheet.